# An exponential growth problem for growing monthly profit. What is the profit after the first year?

Tags: summation, exponential-function

This problem stumped me a bit. Finding the answer was straight forward but I feel like I'm missing some formula that isn't jumping at me.

The problem:
A company makes $1000 profit the first month. They intend to make their profit grow by 10% every month (paraphrasing this part) for the next two years. What is the profit they will make for the first year?

I knew immediately this is some kind of exponential growth function, but didn't have the formula jump out at me.

1000 + (1000 * 1.1) + (1000 * 1.1 * 1.1) + ....

= 1000 + (1000 * 1.1) + (1000 * 1.1^2) + ....

so for the nth month, the profit is:
1000(1 + 1.1^n)

But what's the formula for the entire summation? Is there one? Or do I just add up all of the 12 individual months?

Comment: You are on the right track but the formula that jumped out at you is not quite right. You can't add up all those $(1000 + ...)$ expressions. That would give you the original $1000$ over and over again. If you do it correctly you see that at the end of the year you have $1000(1.1)^{12}$. Subtract the original $1000$ for the profit.

Comment: With $~x = 1.1, ~$ you want $~1000 \times \left(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{11}\right).~$  Are you familiar with the forumula for $~1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n~?$  If not, then I suggest that you perform the following multiplication: $$\left(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n\right) \times (x - 1).$$